# Writing selenium tests againgst bootstrap Checkboxes

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, xpath, gui, css-selectors

I have currently a big Problem to click on a Checkbox in a bootstrap designed GUI.
[image]

In Html it appres like this:
[image]

Does someone know how to press the Button of this checkbox? Because the controls are made in the background and I don't really know how to handle with this. (I have installed Selenium.WebDriver V3.14.0 , ... )

I am using a Helper-Class where I have all my Test-Actions .. Here you see the function which I want to use:
[image]

Already tried the following things:

```
TestHelper.WaitAndClick(By.CssSelector("input[name='ctl00_ctl00_BaseRightContent_MainRightContent_MachineGrid_MachineGridViewGroup'][value='a3bf2573-7005-4b48-9c27-a1a3009f3e57']"), driver, 1);

TestHelper.WaitAndClick(By.XPath("//label[@for='ctl00$ctl00$BaseRightContent$MainRightContent$MachineGrid$customCheck0']"), driver, 1);

TestHelper.WaitAndClick(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_BaseRightContent_MainRightContent_MachineGrid_MachineGridView']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody[2]/tr/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div/label"), driver, 1);
```

Kind Regards
Alex

Comment: Found a very useful Post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908249/debugging-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-error

changed the click in the method to this:  
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(by); 
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(element).Click().Perform();

Answer (score 1):

I could not interact with the checkbox using `click()`, but could send the space key to the `input` element. For example:

`driver.FindElement(by).SendKeys(Keys.Space)`